# How to Post Javascript to a MySQL Database

Tags: php

I have created a form in HTML and I m trying to post the information in the form to a MySQL database. My form makes use of a dynamic list selection that needs to be captured to the database. However when submitting the form I get the following error

Error: Unknown column 'coulmn_name' in 'field list'.

Here is my HTML code for the form

```
    <td height="94"><p align="justify">CALL TRACKER - ADMIN</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <table width="36%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
        <td width="29%" align="right" valign="middle"><strong>Customer Name :</strong></td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" name="customer_name" width="70%" align="left" valign="middle">
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="29%" align="right" valign="middle"><strong>E-Mail Address :</strong></td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" name="customer_email_address" width="70%" align="left" valign="middle">
        </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="29%" align="right" valign="middle"><strong>Case Number :</strong></td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" name="case_number" width="70%" align="left" valign="middle">
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td width="29%" align="right" valign="middle"><strong>MSISDN :</strong></td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" name="msisdn" width="70%" align="left" valign="middle">
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>      
        <td width="29%" align="right" valign="middle">
        <strong>Route Cause :</strong></td>
        <td width="71%" align="left" valign="middle">
        <select name="route_cause" id="category" onChange="javascript: listboxchange1(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
                <!-- <select name="route_cause" id="route_cause"> -->
            <option value="">Select the Call Reason</option>
            <option value="Billing Admin">Billing Admin</option>
            <option value="Customer Care">Customer Care</option>
            <option value="Insurance">Insurance</option>
            <option value="Repairs">Repairs</option>
            <option value="SIM Swap">SIM Swap</option>
            <option value="UTI">UTI</option>

        </select>
        </td>
      </tr>



    <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="middle">
        <strong>Call Type/Indexed To :</strong></td>
        <td align="left" valign="middle">
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" name="calltype_indexedto">
                <!--
                    document.write('<select name="subcategory1" onChange="javascript: listboxchange2(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);"><option value=""></option></select>')
                    -->
        </script>
        </td>



    </tr> 




     <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="middle">
        <strong>Type/TAT :</strong></td>
        <td align="left" valign="middle">
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" name="type_tat">
                <!--
                    document.write('<select name="subcategory2" onChange="javascript: listboxchange3(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);"><option value=""></option></select>')
                    -->
        </script>
        </td>



    </tr> 



    <tr>      
    <td width="29%" align="right" valign="middle">
        <strong>Escalated To :</strong></td>
        <td width="71%" align="left" valign="middle">
        <select name="escalatedto" id="escalated_to">
            <option value="">Select the Escalation</option>
            <option value="Billing Ops">Billing Ops</option>
            <option value="Resolvers">Resolvers</option>
            <option value="Finance">Finance</option>
            <option value="Ressolver">Ressolver</option>
            <option value="Nudebt">Nudebt</option>
            <option value="Transunion">Transunion</option>
            <option value="N/A">N/A</option>


        </select>
        </td>
      </tr>


        <tr>      
    <td width="29%" align="right" valign="middle">
        <strong>Requested By :</strong></td>
        <td width="71%" align="left" valign="middle">
        <select name="requestedby" id="requested_by">
            <option value="">UTI Requested By</option>
            <option value="Billing">Billing</option>
            <option value="Customer Service">Customer Service</option>
            <option value="Insurance">Insurance</option>
            <option value="Management">Management</option>
            <option value="Repairs">Repairs</option>
            <option value="Retail Support">Retail Support</option>
            <option value="Retentions">Retentions</option>
            <option value="SIM Swap">SIM Swap</option>
            <option value="WOW">WOW</option>
            <option value="N/A">N/A</option>


        </select>
        </td>
     </tr>  


    <tr>      
    <td width="29%" align="right" valign="middle">
        <strong>Province :</strong></td>
        <td width="71%" align="left" valign="middle">
        <select name="province" id="province">
            <option value="">Select the Province</option>
            <option value="Eastern Cape">Eastern Cape</option>
            <option value="Gauteng">Gauteng</option>
            <option value="Kwa-Zulu Natal">Kwa-Zulu Natal</option>
            <option value="Limpopo">Limpopo</option>
            <option value="Mpumalanga">Mpumalanga</option>
            <option value="North West">North West</option>
            <option value="Northern Cape">Northern Cape</option>
            <option value="Polokwane">Polokwane</option>
            <option value="Western Cape">Western Cape</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
        </td>
      </tr>

        <tr>
        <td width="29%" align="right" valign="middle"><strong>Comments :</strong></td>
        <td>
        <textarea rows ="5" cols="30" name="comments">
        </textarea>
        </td>
        </tr>


      <tr>
        <td>
        <p>
          <input type="reset" value="Reset Form"><input type="Submit" value="Submit">

Here is my PHP code to write to the Database



    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("hostname"
    ,"mysqusername"
    ,"mysqlpassword");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_select_db("databasename", $con);

    $sql="INSERT INTO customer_services_tracker 
    (customer_name
    ,customer_email_address
    ,case_number
    ,msisdn
    ,route_cause
    ,calltype_indexedto
    ,type_tat
    ,escalatedto
    ,requestedby
    ,province
    ,comments
    )

    VALUES
    ('$_POST[customer_name]'
    ,'$_POST[customer_email_address]'
    ,'$_POST[case_number]'
    ,'$_POST[msisdn]'
    ,'$_POST[route_cause]'
    ,'$_POST[calltype_indexedto]'
    ,'$_POST[type_tat]'
    ,'$_POST[escalatedto]'
    ,'$_POST[requestedby]'
    ,'$_POST[province]'
    ,'$_POST[comments]')";

    $CatName = $rowCat["Name"];

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    echo "1 record added";

    mysql_close($con)
    ?>
```

Comment: You should seriously check for SQL injections and sanitize your input. See mysql_real_escape_string() for reference.

Answer (score 3):

> Error: Unknown column 'coulmn_name' in
>   'field list'.

Your SQL statement probably refers to a **column that does not exist** (in your INSERT INTO, probably). Check the real error message for what name you are using.

One remark: it is very dangerous to construct SQL strings like that (from user inputted data) - if a user fills the 'comments' field with `test'); DROP TABLE customer_services_tracker; --` your query will become... very evil.

Instead, use prepared statements or atleast escape the user input.

Answer (score 0):

You should echo out the sql statement by changing die() to die('SQL: '.$sql.' Error:'.mysql_error());

Also, as an aside you should never just put posted variables into a database, who knows what they contain.

Answer (score 0):

1. You're running not the code you posted here. Save this code into a file and make sure you made this  file the actual form's action.
2. add this code before `$sql =...`:

   `foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) $_POST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);`

Answer (score 0):

This error is sometimes caused by incorrect syntax. Try replacing your apostrophes (') with grave accents (`) and adding these to your column names.